# Facebook SDK CSRF Error

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, request, csrf

I have problem with the Facebook SDK. I keep getting the following error:

> CSRF state token does not match one provided

I don't have any RewriteRule rule as it was suggested before, so thats not the problem.
I changed the getCode() function to the following in order to know where is the problem:

```
  protected function getCode() {
if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
  if ($this->state !== null &&
      isset($_REQUEST['state']) &&
      $this->state === $_REQUEST['state']) {

    // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
    $this->state = null;
    $this->clearPersistentData('state');
    return $_REQUEST['code'];
  } else {
    $add = "";
    if ($this->state == null)
        $add .= " State is null";
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['state']))
        $add .= " State is not set";
    if ($this->state !== $_REQUEST['state'])
        $add .= " States are not that same";
    self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided. problem:' . $add);
    return false;
  }
}

return false;
```

}

and after I rerun the login script now I get the following error:

> CSRF state token does not match one provided. problem: State is null States are not that same

Does any one know how to fix this up?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using the facebook api?

Comment: Where/how are you setting `$this->state` outside of that method?

Comment: @CBroe, it should be set up automatically in the Facebook API when I get the login URL. check line 579: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

Comment: Ah, so you are using the original PHP SDK then, OK. Could be a problem with the session – please check if the transfer of the session ID to the next script works and that the session is picked up correctly again.

Comment: @datasage, Im using it like this `$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  ));` then `$user = $facebook->getUser();` and `if(!$user){
  // Get login URL
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope'   => 'email, user_about_me',
   'redirect_uri' => $site_url,
   ));
 }` and if `if ($user) echo "u r logged in";`

Comment: @CBroe how can I check that?

Comment: Display the session ID (and maybe session contents as well) at the beginning of each script, using var_dump/print_r. (After creating the Facebook object instance, that starts the session automatically.)

Comment: @CBroe, I'm starting a session by `session_start();` at the beginning of each page, doesn't that already start the session?

Comment: Yes, the SDK only starts one itself if there isn’t one. Still, do the very basic debugging steps I told you.

Comment: @CBroe `$this->state` is not set but all else works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by making sure that the domain I send the request from is same as the one I get back the answer. In other words wwww.website.com is different from website.com.

Answer (score -1):

replace the `getCode` function with:

```
protected function getCode() {
  $server_info = array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE);

  if (isset($server_info['code'])) {
  if ($this->state !== null &&
  isset($server_info['state']) &&
  $this->state === $server_info['state']) {

// CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
    $this->state = null;
    $this->clearPersistentData('state');
    return $server_info['code'];
} else {
    self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
    return false;
  }
}

return false;
}
```

The code simply combines the $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE arrays as with how $_REQUEST used to work prior to PHP 5.3.0. hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately `$this->state` is not set so it did not work but thank you